# How to send drawable Images from android app as MMS or on any social media app?

Tags: android

I'm not able to share my image from the app for messaging as an attachment
I have a list of int array of drawable images

```
final int [] imagelistId={
        R.drawable.birthday1,
        R.drawable.birthday2,
        R.drawable.birthday3,
        R.drawable.birthday4,
        R.drawable.birthday5,
        R.drawable.birthday6,
    };
```

After that i have this code for sharing an image as an attachment

```
smsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                // add the message at the sms_body extra field
                smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mmsto:"));
                smsIntent.setType("image/*");
                smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Image");
                smsIntent.putExtra("subject", "Image Message");
                smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.finalgreetings/" + imagelistId[pos]) );
                try{
                    mcontext.startActivity(smsIntent);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Your sms has failed...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

I have seen many stack overflow questions but none answered my problem.
I have also read about converting drawable to bitmap and save to internal or external storage then share it but dont know how to do it.
Kindly suggest me best and easy solution. Thanx in advance.

Comment: you want to share image from drawable folder...???

Comment: Yup..these images are in drawable folder and i want to share them on different social apps or through mms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..!!!

```
smsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage);//put here your image id
                String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/LatestShare.png";
                OutputStream out = null;
                File file = new File(path);
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                path = file.getPath();
                Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/png");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the comment but its not working it gives error on attaching to gmail " Cant attach an empty file"

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mcontext.getResources(), imagelistId[pos]);
                 
i have changed this in your code other than that everything else is same.

Comment: Yup it contains all the drawable ids as you can see from my top code it also contains the imagelistId [] array.

Comment: It worked after adding permission in menifest file as follows

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Can you tell me the way how to do  the same for internal storage?

Comment: No the solution u told is using external storage which is sd card.Im asking about internal storage which is ROM.

Comment: Im using the code u posted its working fine when i select an image 1st time it shows as an attachment in message then i discard that message and selects another image to share. After that message app opens and it shows the previous image as an attachment instead of the new 1.
When i remove that attachment and discard that message after that share another image then it shows the selected image instead of previous selected..Why is this so??

Comment: Its working on Android cellphone correctly but not on emulator that was the problem.:D

Comment: its working fine on android cellphone but not on emulator may be its emulator issue.:)